# Properties of Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis

Let v $\in H$ with $H$ Hilbert space and let $M$ a closed set.

It's right that $M+v=\{m+v: m\in M \}$ is a closed subset of $H$?

If $M$ is a closed subset then $M+v$ is closed and convex?

Comment: Since $x\mapsto x + v$ is a homeomorphism, $M+v$ is closed iff $M$ is closed. Since the map is affine, $M + v$ is convex iff $M$ is convex

Comment: if $M$ is closed then $M+v$ is closed as well. In order for $M+v$ to be convex, $M$ needs to convex